# Buggy CSS Transitions when Video Element not present

Tags: css, video, transition

Hi I am in the process of developing my [website](http://georgearnall.com). Please understand it is work in progress.

I have a menu bar which when scrolled, will stick to the top and a background will fade in and a border will slide out.

Here is a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/0Y2d3V2u0Y1g) of an example of what it does.

What makes this even more strange is that when there is a [video element present](http://georgearnall.com/v2) it does not do this. You can even try deleting the video element from this page and then it starts doing it. (Located in < header>, < div class="feature-content">, < video> )

I have never seen this before with a CSS transition. I have tried it with Firefox 17 and Chrome 27 for Mac.

Does anyone have any ideas ?
Thanks :)

**Edit**: I apologise for not remembering I had restriced acess to the server with a redirect, this has now been fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something to do with animate.css. By removing this it started working correctly again.